# Finding $\mu(T,v)$ and $\mu(P,v)$ from fundamental equation $s(u,v)$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

I need to find $\mu(P,v)$ (where $\mu$ is the chemical potential) and $\mu(T,v)$ for a system whose fundamental equation in the representation of entropy I do know. All the information I have is that it's a simple and closed system with only one type of chemical compound, and I need to describe what its isobars and isotherms look like on a $\mu - v$ diagram. It's fundamental equation is $$s(u,v) = A(u^2 v)^{1/4}$$ With A being a positive constant. I have derived its fundamental equation in extensive form (i.e. with the number of moles $N$ in it), which is $S(U,V,N) = A U^{1/2} V^{1/4} N^{1/4}$, but I have been unable to find the equations I'm looking for. How could I approach this problem?

(I know that, once I have $\mu(P,v)$ and $\mu(T,v)$, all I have to do is make P and T constant, respectively, and check the resulting equation, which will be some monomial in $v$ in both cases. It's finding those two functions that I'm having trouble with. Thanks everyone!)

Comment: Have you tried playing with maxwell's relations and thermodynamic potentials in general? $dU = TdS - pdV + \mu dN$ which gives you $1/T = \frac{\partial{S}}{\partial{U}}$ and $p/T = \frac{\partial{S}}{\partial{V}}$ and $\mu/T = \frac{\partial{S}}{\partial{N}}$. Gibbs free energy could also maybe store some information as the temperature and pressure are controlled in it. $\mu = (\partial{G}/\partial{N})_{p, T}$

Answer (score 1):

From the fundamental equation you can obtain  the temperature, pressure and chemical potential by differentiation wrt their respective extensive parameters. You will obtain $T(u,v)$, $p(u,v)$ and $\mu(u,v)$. Note that $T(U,V,N) = T(u,v)$, (same for the others) since they are intensive variables.

Then simply invert the equation of temperature to get $u(T,v)$, and substitute in the expression of the chemical potential to obtain $\mu = \mu(u(T,v),v)=\mu(T,v)$. Do the same for the pressure $p(u,v)$ to obtain $u(p,v)$ and therefore $\mu(u(p,v),v)=\mu (p,v)$.

Hope it helps.

Comment: What a great answer! It seems obvious now, but I couldn't figure it out. Thanks!